# NPE at TreeTableRenderer.encodeEnd

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

This is my TreeTable definition on xhtml page:

```
<p:treeTable var="r" value="#{mybean.tree}">
```

I can see in catalina.out file that every day this happens a few times:

```
12-Jan-2015 10:13:00.119 SEVERE [ajp-apr-8009-exec-211] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/my_page.xhtml]
     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTableRenderer.encodeEnd(TreeTableRenderer.java:127)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:648)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
        at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:831)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2344)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    12-Jan-2015 10:13:00.120 SEVERE [ajp-apr-8009-exec-211] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTableRenderer.encodeEnd(TreeTableRenderer.java:127)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:648)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
        at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:831)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2344)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I haven't gottten any user complaints and am not sure yet what the user is doing when this happens. I was assuming she is just opening the page but because of `handlePartialResponseError` I guess it could be also expanding/collapsing.

Does the error indicate that my object is `null` in one entry of the tree? In my code I have made sure no nulls are added so this should not be the case.

`mybean` is a `@SessionScoped` `@ManagedBean` (used to be `@ViewScoped` but now the tree is cached for each user).

My setup is:

- Tomcat 8.0.15
- Mojarra 2.2.8
- Primefaces 5.1
- RHEL 7.0

Comment: Can happen if the model has incompatibly concurrently changed. What scope is `#{mybean.tree}` put in? Does the code guarantee that the instance isn't shared by another request?

Comment: Thank you, added the scope to question. Based on that information do I need to quarantee (how?) "that the instance isn't shared by another request"?

Comment: A session scoped bean is shared by multiple requests/views. If the model is mutable, then this can indeed end up in concurrency (threadsafety) trouble like this when performed simultaneously from multiple requests/views. The risk is higher if the webapp is "slow" and the enduser is very well versed with working in multiple browser tabs/windows. Try putting back the bean in view scope and observe if the problem remains or not.

Comment: One reason for using session scope is preserving expand/collapse state and that's why I cannot go back to view scope unless there are serious user complaints. Sometimes the Tree can be large and take about 10 seconds to build. I will do some testing opening it in multiple tabs at the same time.

Comment: Expand/collapse state isn't session scoped data. It's view scoped data. Moreover, this would even further increase the risk into trouble when manipulated in multiple browser tabs/windows. View scoped data should be hold in a view scoped bean, not in a session scoped bean. If you had trouble with it, it's caused elsewhere. Perhaps it was actually a request scoped bean, or it was behaving like a request scoped bean because the view was for some reason destroyed/recreated on every request.

Comment: Sorry not following. When the user leaves the page that shows this treetable and comes back she wants to see the expand/collapse state as she left it. If I'm using view scope the bean will be gone and the tree will have to be rebuilt when the user comes back. EDIT: Do you mean that if she comes back soon enough the view scoped bean is still there?

Comment: I opened the page on a new tab while the tree was still building but did not get any errors. I will have to add some logging to find out what exactly is going on when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BalusC wrote in his comment this exception occurs when backend tree is changed while UI tree is building.

When `p:treeTable` builds it calls `getTree()` method really many times, at least once for each category. If one of these calls receives a `TreeNode` object which does not equal the others this exception will be thrown.

In my code I made sure `getTree()` will always return the same `TreeNode` object if it was last called by the same user less than 10ms ago. That fixed it.

Better solution would be a fix in *PrimeFaces* that would make `p:treeTable` request `TreeNode` object only once.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think thats a good solution. The code should look more like this:

```
public TreeNode getRoot() {
    checkSession();
    if (root == null) {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode(data, null);
    }
    return root;   
 }
```

To ensure that it's the same object (right scope of bean assumed)

Michael

Comment: Thanks. What is `checkSession();`?

Answer (score 0):

Call following JS function `onstart` of `<p:ajax event="select" onstart="func()" />`.

```
function func(){
    var originalVal = $('<YOUR_TREETABLE_ID>_selection').val();
    var arr = originalVal.split(',');
    $('<YOUR_TREETABLE_ID>_selection').val(arr[arr.length-1]);
}
```